# Comment décrire un enseignant qui cherche à amener ses étudiants à des idées qui ne sont pas les leurs ?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Prenons l’exemple d’un professeur de philosophie qui ferait couler un étudiant parce que les idées de ce dernier divergeraient des idées de ce premier, et ce, malgré une argumentation inébranlable. Pourrait-on qualifier ce professeur de propagandiste ou d’influenceur impitoyable, impitoyable sur les idées qui ne sont pas en accord avec les siennes ?

*Si vous avez une autre façon en tête de formuler la première phrase citée dans les détails qui permet de se passer de « ce premier » et de « ce dernier », n’hésitez pas à me la présenter.* Mon intuition me dit que quelque chose cloche dans cette phrase mais je n’ai pas la force d’esprit d’y remédier.

Comment: Est-ce que tu cherches des synonymes de propagandiste (dico) ou s'agit-il de la tournure de *ce premier* etc dans la phrase ?

Comment: @livresque Je dirais que je cherche surtout une reformulation sans « ce premier » !

Comment: @livresque La reprise de l’information, c’est ma bête noire.

Comment: Mais je cherche aussi un terme qui pourrait décrire l’enseignant en question en un terme ou en faisant appel à une expression. Je ne sais pas si « propagandiste » est le terme adapté au contexte.

Comment: S'agissant d'un prof de philo, je dirais simplement qu'il est mauvais. Son rôle n'est pas de diffuser ses propres idées, mais de fournir aux élèves les sources et la méthode pour qu'ils développent les leurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Prenons l’exemple d’un professeur de philosophie qui pénaliserait un étudiant pour des opinions divergentes, et ce malgré une argumentation implacable. Pourrait-on qualifier ce professeur de propagandiste ou d’idéologue intransigeant, intransigeant avec des idées qui ne seraient pas en accord avec les siennes ?*

Answer (score 0):

Pour une reformulation épurée, voir la réponse de [user Necklondon](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/51172/17649).

En ce qui concerne la description  j'ajouterai   les points de  vue suivants.

D'un côté, il est question d'opinions, de l'autre, d'argument implacable, ce qui constitue une certaine contradiction. Comme les arguments  implacables se dévoilent être implacables dans l'esprit de n'importe quel théoricien du sujet, ce professeur aurait beaucoup de monde contre lui, et vraisemblablement il n'est pas question  d'arguments implacables, surtout comme le  domaine dont il s'agit est la philosophie. Néanmoins, en tant  que  professeur, cet individu est chargé d'ouvrir  l'esprit à des étudiants sur  un certain sujet, ce qui  signifie les guider dans l'apprentissage des notions  connues  le concernant et vérifier que l'assimilation est correcte, mais pas plus. Les  opinions personnelles ont leur place, accessoirement, mais c'est  une petite place avant q'une thèse devienne une sérieuse possibilité (et de toute façon les thèses ne sont pas des collections d'opinions personnelles puisqu'elles doivent reposer sur un nombre substantiel de références).

Il n'en est pas moins  vrai que ce personnage est coupable d'un comportement qui porte un  préjudice à ses élèves, tout au moins certains d'entre eux. De tels actes pénalisants de la part d'un professeur relèvent de la faute professionnelle. (En  France, c'est même un principe de la Constitution : « *Article 10 Nul ne doit être inquiété pour ses opinions, même religieuses, pourvu que leur manifestation ne trouble pas l'ordre public établi par la loi*. ».)  Donc ses actions vont bien au-delà de l'acte de propagande (un terme qui implique  le mensonge et non la force) et l'appeler un propagandiste ne serait pas faire justice de ses actes. Cependant, je ne parviens pas à trouver un terme assez court pour décrire son attitude, sa faute. En pensant au plus  précis et au plus court je ne vois qu'une quasi-répétition de la formule déjà utilisée ci-dessus : « *enseignant coupable d'un comportement préjudiciable pour ses élèves* » (ce qui ne prend toujours pas en compte les deux aspects du préjudice, l'action coercitive en vue de changer les opinions et la répression s'ensuivant par le moyen de mauvais avis pour les étudiants récalcitrants.  Un  terme plus court mais plus général pourrait être utile : je pense à « *professeur coupable d'abus d'autorité* ».

Comment: Il serait alors question de quel genre d’arguments ? Si vous aviez à qualifier les arguments de quelqu’un en philosophie qui sauraient vous convaincre ? Des arguments satisfaisants ? Des arguments convaincants ?

Comment: Pour éviter ladite contradiction interne.

Comment: @Pretzel Il  existe bien  en philosophie des arguments incontournables, c'est à dire fondés sur la logique pure, et donc que personne ne peut réfuter, mais la philosophie est loin d'être  fondée sur la logique ; cependant, de nos jours l'instruction d'un étudiant en philosophie comprend une formation fondamentale en logique. Le positivisme, par exemple, ne se prouve pas, on l'accepte ou on le rejette sur la base d'une expérience générale des sciences, ce que l'on a pu en  conclure ; (1/2)

Comment: @Pretzel   il en  va  de même pour tous les systèmes  philosophiques : c'est  une question de « foi intellectuelle ». Je m'en tiendrais donc à des termes tels que « satisfaisant », « convaincant », « raisonnable », « acceptable », « plein de bon sens », etc. (2/2)